# Error before install Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

When I want install Ubuntu 18.04 and new Debian or Kali, before I install it I get the error below. My laptop is Lenovo y510p and I  try

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

but it didn't help me and I update my bios to last version

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x22 (or later)
```

Comment: Hi. You might find this question/answer useful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410854/tsc-deadline-disabled-due-to-errata